# How can I remove specific parts of text in files with Python?

Tags: python

I got a file which contains a lot of stuff like that:

```
tile.lotr:oreTin.name=Zinnerz
```

I would like to remove everything before the equal sign and itself. So how can I remove this part of the text, so that in this case only `"Zinnerz"` is in the txt-file afterwards.

Another sample

```
generator.middleEarth=Mittelerde
generator.middleEarth.info=Beginne sofort deine epischen Abenteuer...
generator.meClassic=Nostalgik-ME
generator.meClassic.info=Reise durch Mittelerde, wie in alten Zeiten...

tile.lotr:rock.0.name=Mordor-Fels
tile.lotr:rock.1.name=Gondor-Fels
tile.lotr:rock.2.name=Rohan-Fels
tile.lotr:rock.3.name=Luigon
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: If you could post a longer sample of the text as well as what approaches you have tried so far you will probably get more help.

Comment: `t = 'tile.lotr:oreTin.name=Zinnerz'` `print(t.split('=')[1])`

Answer (score 0):

Use the split method.

```
with open('file.txt',r) as f
for string in f :
    l = string.split("=")
    print(l[1])
```

You can write the new string, `l[1]` to a new file by opening it in write mode

Comment: And how can I open the file and make every line a string?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: you should open files using `with` so that they are close automatically.

Answer (score 0):

first read the file and all the lines using `readlines()` method store it in a variable,

```
lines=file.readlines()
```

now loop over each line in your file something like this

```
for line in lines:
```

assuming there is only one '=' in one line of your text file use this

```
newvar+=string.split('=')[1]
newvar+='\n'
```

now open your file in write mode and overwrite the file with this string

Comment: I am sorry if I ddin't specify. The whole file contains a bunch of these lines